# MySQL - Query to find a continuous range of unused values

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, algorithm

I have a table containing integer values from 0 to some large number N, but has some number gaps. I'm trying to write an efficient query that'll find the first set of **continuous** values of some length that are within 0 and N but *are not* contained in the said table. This has applications to find unused ids, etc.

For example, given the set

> [1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,14,15]

, find a range of continuous 5 numbers that aren't in the set. It should be

> [5,6,7,8,9]

. How do I write this in a single, efficient query? thanks.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I think your only option is to go through every single row until you find it...

Comment: This shouldn't be labeled with "algorihm" tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a great chapter from **SQL Server MVP Deep Dives** book on this subject.

http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf

Here's one of solutions

```
WITH StartingPoints AS
(
SELECT seqval, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY seqval) AS rownum
FROM dbo.NumSeq AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM dbo.NumSeq AS B
WHERE B.seqval = A.seqval - 1)
),
EndingPoints AS
(
SELECT seqval, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY seqval) AS rownum
FROM dbo.NumSeq AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM dbo.NumSeq AS B
WHERE B.seqval = A.seqval + 1)
)
SELECT S.seqval AS start_range, E.seqval AS end_range
FROM StartingPoints AS S
JOIN EndingPoints AS E
ON E.rownum = S.rownum;
```

Comment: It always amazes me what you can do with just an SQL statement

Comment: Brilliant... I've been trying to wrap my head around this problem for months (for a personal project, so wasn't urgent)... I tried recursive CTE's, but this is absolutely spot on